# Portforwarding on Huawei B818-260

Tags: wireless-networking, router, vpn, wired-networking

I got a Huawei modem/router for 4G broadband at home with a contract for that. We have also a IP Camera, Foscam FI9805W, which worked during several yw\ears now, but we cannot use it with an app on our mobile phone.
Usually there must forwardet ports before we could use it, but in the router we have now, I cannot find how to do so .

The route is one we got from Telenor in Norway.

I there anyone out there which has the same problems or knows how to solve it??

Kind regards in advance.

Comment: Mobile connections usually use [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. "